# Why was primality test thought to be NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np

To check if $n$ is prime, one only need to try dividing $n$ by numbers up to $\sqrt{n}$, meaning that the complexity would be $O(\sqrt{n})$. In my opinion, $O(\sqrt{n}) < O(n)$ so this simple algorithm is already P. But why did people think that primality test is NP, and were surprised by the AKS primality test?

Comment: If something is in P then it is automatically in NP. You seem to be using "NP" as shorthand for either "NP - P" or "NP-complete".

Comment: And I don't think many people thought it was NP-complete; it doesn't seem that you can use it to solve other problems in NP. Then it was shown to be in NP and co-NP, which was odd. Many people believed it was "slightly" exponential.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start, any decision problem with a witness verifiable for a "yes" answer in polynomial time is in NP.

$\bullet$ The problem 'Is $p$ composite?' has a witness $k$, and it can be tested in polynomial time whether $k$ divides $p$, therefore is in NP.

$\bullet$ The problem 'Is $p$ prime?' has a polynomial certificate (which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate)), therefore is also in NP.

Now, your complexity analysis is not correct. If your input is a number $p$, then the input size is $\log (p)$, since you need $log(p)$ bits to represent it. Therefore, $n=\log(p)$ and $\sqrt{p}=\frac{1}{2} \log(p)$ bits. So the time required (in respect to $n$) checking all the numbers up to $\sqrt{p}$ will be $2^{\frac{1}{2}n}$, and is in fact exponential in terms of input size $n$.

---

The question "Where exactly does the Primality problem lie" has been answered in the link [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/159/is-integer-factorization-an-np-complete-problem)

Comment: "Is p composite" is obviously in NP, because you can bring a witness easily. "Is p prime" is in NP, but not obviously at all - there is a quite deep theorem that every prime p has a short prove of being prime, which I think involves complete factorisations of p+1 and/or p-1.

Comment: @gnasher729 thank you for spotting it! I edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think many people thought it was NP-complete; it doesn't seem that you can use it to solve other problems in NP (which is required for NP-complete). Then it was shown to be in NP and co-NP, which was odd.

And you could of course do probabilistic tests in polynomial time. It is quite likely that there is a not very large polynomial p(n) so that doing p(n) probabilistic tests proves indeed that a number of size n is a prime. In which case primality was always in P. (It's just hard to prove).